# Remove xml namespaces in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I am trying to remove the xml namespaces using php, however I am having difficulty in achieving this.

For example, I would like the following xml code response from a remote server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <data>
            <id>1</id>
            <id>2</id>
            <id>3</id>
        </data>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

to be parsed on a local server to be;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <id>1</id>
    <id>2</id>
    <id>3</id>
</data>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I see you're trying to modify a soap payload. Are you using the php soap client?

Comment: So you don't want to remove the namespace, but you want to get the content of Envelope->Body?

Comment: What about just find/replace `<soap:` to `<` before you parse your XML (terrible... i know)

Comment: @Scuzzy - I'm using curl_exec to send soap xml and the response I receive is soap xml

Comment: @rickdenhaan - yes please.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily extract the data using XPath and SimpleXML, this code takes a string (this uses `file_get_contents`, I think you get it from cURL) and convert it to an XML document.  Then uses XPath to extract the `<soap:Body>` children nodes (using `//soap:Body/*`) - this will give a list of matching nodes.  To output the data it just uses `asXML()`...

```
$data = file_get_contents("data.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$body = $xml->xpath("//soap:Body/*");
echo $body[0]->asXML();
```